# how to add multiple events JQuery

Tags: jquery, events, onsubmit

I want to add onsubmit()'s event to my $(document).ready(function
but i have already an class event type .on("blur", function)
how can I do it?

`$(document).ready(function myFunction() { $('.myClass').on("blur", function (e) { });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(
    function myFunction() {
        $('.myClass').on("blur, onsubmit", function (e) { 
            /** Your code here **/ 
        });
    }
)
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(
    function myFunction() {
        $('.myClass').on("blur", function (e) {
            /** Your code here **/
        });
        $('.myClass').on("onsubmit", function (e) {
            /** Your code here **/
        });
    }
)
```

Comment: First option doesn't work and second its duplicate code

Comment: But you asked about multiple events. First option about multiple events. What is your task can you explain with more detail and if is it possible to provide screenshots

Comment: i want to check de conditions when i do a blur and when i send the form